# Add different icons for teams custom apps outline?

Tags: c#, reactjs, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a problem, I want to add different icons when my app is selected and when my app is not selected in teams, something similar to what we have for the default teams buttons: [not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLa0J.png) and [selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rwFn.png).

The problem is we only have one option to add in the main [app package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4lSI.png).

Comment: We do not have such provision to define multiple color.png files in manifest. So currently we can not have different icons when your app is selected/not selected.

Also let us know where you are trying this action ? 
While installing the app from store/app studio?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have such provision to define multiple color.png files in manifest file. So currently we can not have different icons when your app is selected/not selected.